# Is this the right way to view infinity in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

So, I've lately been having confusion on how to understand infinity, but I think I have progress in my intuition. So, I'd appreciate if someone would let me know if I'm on the right track, and which parts I still don't have right.

This is my understanding so far. Originally I had looked at the infinite intersection: $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
I had thought that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) \neq \emptyset$ since for an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the intersection is non-empty. Thereofre, since every element in the intersection is non-empty, it must be that the total intersection is non-empty since the intervals are nested.

My current understanding is this: that while the above information could be used to prove that any finite/arbitrarily long intersection is non-empty, an arbitrarily large number will never cover all of $\mathbb{N}$. I reasoned that for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}n$ does not cover all the natural numbers, since $m+1 \notin \bigcup_{n=1}^{m}n$. So while it covers arbitrarily many natural numbers, it can't possibly cover *all* of them.

So the only way to cover all of the natural numbers is using some object which is not in $\mathbb{N}$ and is greater than all natural numbers. If I have an $M$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},M > n$, then $\mathbb{N} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{M}n$. So, even if the intersection is non-empty for each natural number, its still neccesary to check that $(0,\frac{1}{M})$ is non-empty. Checking this, gives that its non-empty only if $\exists n\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } 0<\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{M}$. Since this implies $M<n$, but $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, M>n $, then this fails for all natural numbers.

While my explanation is very unrigorous, it seems like it can be formalized by using limit ordinals, and including limit ordinals as a requirement when doing induction. Is this correct? Is this the right way to view these problems? Also, does a value the same size as the limit oridinal occur infinite times, or does it only "occur" at the end? More formally, would $$\left|\bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N}} \begin{cases} \emptyset, \text{if} \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) \neq \emptyset \\\{n\},\text{otherwise} \end{cases} \right|$$
be 0, or $\omega$?

Comment: I see many flaws in your argumentation.  The first one is in the sentence "since for an arbitrary n∈N, the intersection is non-empty." which lacks meaning.  Could you elaborate on it?  Incidentally, that intersection is empty.

Comment: @Ruy For example, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 0<\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$, since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 0<n<n+1$. So, each individual interval is non-empty. In that sentence, I mean to convey that since each individual interval is non-empty, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^m\left(0,\frac{1}{n} \right ) \neq \emptyset$. So, the intersections of the intervals up to any choosen natural number m is non-empty. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is much better.  Next I would argue that $\bigcup_{n=1}^m n$ makes no sense because unions apply exclusively to sets, rather than numbers.

Comment: You're overthinking it. If $\displaystyle x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} (0, \frac{1}{n})$ then $x \in (0, \frac{1}{n})$ for every $n$. But for any $x > 0$, $\exists n$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < x$ so that there is no such $x$. So the intersection is empty.

Comment: @Ruy Okay, I could replace that with the set $A = \{n, n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n \leq m\}$.

Comment: @user4894 I agree thats a valid proof, and it does maybe look like I'm overthinking in the context of this one problem. The main difficulty isn't this individual problem, but more of understanding how something can be true for an arbitrarily large natural number but *not* be true for all natural numbers. This question represents what I think is a solution to that what appeared to me as a contradiction--that something could be true for as many natural numbers as one likes, but still be false for *all* natural numbers.

Comment: @CalebBriggs What's true is that as you said, you can truncate the intersection at any finite $n$ and the intersection is always nonempty. This shows that what's true in every finite case is not always true in the limit. For example for each $n$, $\frac{1}{n} >  0$; yet the limit is $0$. An imperfect analogy but I hope you get the idea. But what I meant by overthinking it is that instead of trying to "figure out" the general meaning, just focus on mastering the formalism of a proof such as I gave; and the intuition will follow.

Comment: @Ruy I could change the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^M$ with $B=\{n,n \in \mathbb{N} \wedge n \leq M\}$. Since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, M > n$, then $\mathbb{N}  \subset B$

Comment: @user4894 Is mastering the formalism first the general strategy for a real analysis class? Maybe I've been going about it wrong by trying to understand the intuition first and then having the formalism follow--was that your expierence taking the class?

Comment: I think this is a valid preocupation but in the end we need to adjust our intuition to the cold hard logic of Math.  Fortunately quite often our intuition is right but in some key points it is irremediably wrong!

Comment: @CalebBriggs That is a really good question. I think you need to go back and forth between the formalism and the intuition. I would say that what I wrote is a suggestion; and that can take from it whatever you find helpful and ignore the rest. You definitely need to follow your own path. But in this particular problem, I personally think nailing the proof as I wrote it is more helpful than ... well, than overthinking it. Just my two cents and not to be considered binding on your own learning style.

Comment: @user4894 Thank you for your advice! Advice from an experienced mathematician is especially useful since I have learned mostly from self-studying, so this will be really useful for learning this subject--I appreciate it!

Comment: "Maybe I've been going about it wrong by trying to understand the intuition first" Your intuition should tell you that $\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} (0, \frac{1}{n})$ is empty, because those intervals are getting smaller and smaller and there's no way a number could belong to all of them.

Comment: @CalebBriggs Glad I could help. I'm a former student who did well in that course. I'm in no way a mathematician as some around here are. I wanted to add something to my proof. Why is it that $\forall x > 0 \ \exists n$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < x$? It's because $\mathbb R$ is Archimedean. This is an important property of the reals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here.

---

First, there seems to be an issue with a fact of typical induction that (in my experience) sometimes escapes students:
a statement being true for *each* $n\in\Bbb N$ does not mean it 'spills over' to infinity.

Typical induction goes as follows:
$P(n)$ is a proposition about $n\in\Bbb N$.
If $P(0)$ is true and if $P(n)$ being true implies $P(n+1)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Notice how this is fundamentally a result about natural numbers, all of which are finite.
Infinity is not a natural number.
You yourself have pointed that out, and indeed in mentioning ordinals it seems you might be acquainted with (or would be interested in) [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). Transfinite induction is what's used when we want a proposition to 'spill over' to infinity, and it tells us precisely that one needs to take special care with this transition (more precisely, the case of limit ordinals needs its own inductive step).

---

Moreover, and somewhat related, is the fact that, outside the context of induction, but in the context of limits, there are properties that may hold in each term of a limit but fail to hold in the limit.

You might have heard of fluke proofs that $\pi = 4$, by starting from a square that is progressively made to approach the circle that inscribes it.
In each step the resulting polygon preserves the perimeter of the initial square, and yet in the limit, we get the circle.
This is an example where the kind of convergence matters.
In this case, the limiting process is a pointwise convergence, for which plenty of properties fail to hold over the limit.
There are other kinds of stronger convergence (like uniform convergence), for which more properties hold over the limit.

Now, perhaps this example was discrete, and therefore it still smells of typical induction.
Of course, rather than consider it to be done in steps, you could smooth out the transition between each step along the real numbers, so the whole thing becomes a continuous limit.

But you can observe this in much simpler cases too.
Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}1/x$.
This is a continuous limit, and for every $x>0$ the expression $1/x$ is positive.
And yet, the limit is $0$ (non positive).

---

Finally, there seems to be just plain misunderstanding about what the symbol $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ means.
Or rather, given what you state in your question, it seems your intuition fails to conform to the understanding of the symbol.

There are plenty of counterintuitive things in mathematics.
Most paradoxes are usually named so not because they're *wrong*, but because when they were found out, they were deemed counterintuitive.

It is important to be able to recognize when our intuition fails.
This is usually a moment of growth: if we understand *a posteriori* why something fails, we'll have learned something valuable from it.
This applies to both points I shared previously: we learned something about induction, and we learned something about limits.

In the case of $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$, the meaning is the set of elements that belong to *all* $A_n$.
In your example question, $A_n = (0,1/n)$.
We have

$$\begin{align}
a \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(0,\frac1n\right)
&\iff \forall n\in\Bbb N, a \in\left(0,\frac1n\right)
\\&\iff \forall n\in\Bbb N, 0 < a < \frac1n
\end{align}$$

so $a$ is positive, and yet, $n<1/a$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.
We are forced to conclude that no such $a$ exists, so the intersection $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(0,\frac1n\right)$ must be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite collections are very different from finite collections.

From the definition of $\Bbb R,$ there is no positive $r\in \Bbb R$ that is less than $1/n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$ so $\cap_{n\in\Bbb N}(0,1/n)=\emptyset.$

When you have an infinite sequence $(t_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ of things, nothing happens at the end because there is no end.